# Do PCB manufacturers provide SMT soldering services for small runs (qty. 5)?

Tags: pcb, soldering

I don't know whether this question was asked before or off-topic but I couldn't think of another site to have better answer than this stackexchange.

I sometimes build prototypes using two or three ready boards. Like using a small evolution MCU board a specific sensor with SPI, I2C, DAC ect. And in this case, I do not need to make the cost low because the circuit will be part of a very expensive large system and I maybe need max five circuits.

PCB itself can be designed by me but the thing is there's no skills, time and equipment for soldering hundreds of surface mount components. And in this case hiring someone for the purpose and buying equipment is also overkill expensive since as I mentioned only five pieces needed. My question is, in such circumstance do the PCB manufacturers provide also soldering services with extra payment or are there separate ones just perform this or there is no such thing exists.

Comment: There are companys that specialize in low volume assembly, take a look at https://pcbshopper.com/ for some of them.

Comment: I can't watch a YouTube electronics video without being bombarded by ads for services that will assemble small numbers of PCBs for tens of dollars. Search, tons of tutorials, project logs and instruction videos showing exactly how to do this.

Comment: Slight frame-challenge: Could you invest some time and effort into making your own solder reflow oven? I did it with the cheapest toaster oven I could find (entirely mechanical controls that I could set out of the way and not have to remove), plus a one-off circuit and software. Plug the oven into a software-controlled triac-dimmed outlet, and use a properly-rated temperature sensor of some kind as feedback to that software. Add a hobby servo to open the door for the final fast cooling, and a user-interface to your liking (a good one will take most of the code), and you've pretty much got it.

Comment: Yes. Companies such as JLCPCB and PCBWAY will quote on assembly as well as fabrication. You may receive detailed questions about solder mask and overlay clearances, etc, that can be a little bit difficult to understand and answer.

Comment: @user1850479: You need the uBlock Origin and SponsorBlock browser plugins (available for at least Firefox).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your title; please use titles that contain the question, rather than ones that just say "there's a question about X in the body."

Comment: You can get the boards fabbed and assembled in China for a reasonable cost even if you only need 5. Just send them a quote package (gerbers, including pick and place data and also the BOM).

Comment: JLCPCB and PCBWAY do, in my opinion some comments are somewhat negative to it (like it’s tough to do), my experience is it’s easy. I make an answer of mine.

Comment: Not an anwer, but maybe an alternative solution ?
https://eu.beta-layout.com/estore/order_product_details.html?p=624

Answer (score 10):

It's called an assembly service. This may be provided by the same place that makes the PCB or by a different place that does nothing but assemble PCBs.

The more automated assembly (which is most of them) are not intended for five pieces because there are setup costs for the equipment involvement. They will gladly assemble five boards for you, but they will charge that fixed setup cost either way and it will get amortized across 5 pieces instead of 5000.

They also likely have some good manual soldering equipment for rework and fixes, but if you are hoping they will instead assign a human to solder your five boards for you and not charge the setup cost, you're going to be disappointed because both costs are for the labour of a human.

If the board is too complicated for you to solder, either because there are too many components or the components cannot be readily soldered by hand, then the cost for manual assembly of a few boards is going to approach the setup cost for automated assembly.

The setup costs for automated assembly tend to be right around the costs to get some good manual soldering equipment anyways (not a pick and place machine and reflow oven) so if you only have five boards and they can be manually assembled, most just buy the equipment and do it themselves since you recoup costs on being able to re-use that equipment. This also has the benefit that assembly and boards are not perfect, especially the first time around and you need equipment to debug and troubleshoot. You probably don't want to be respinning boards over and over again and paying for assembly for testing a bunch of minor fixes.

But if your board can't be assembled manually by equipment you can afford then you have no choice. The assembler doesn't care how many boards you need to put together as long as you're willing to pay what they want.

Comment: Just to give some scale for the setup cost, cheap places like PCBWay would usually charge a few hundred dollars for assembly of a small quantity of boards.

Answer (score 9):

While I'm sure that specific recommendations are beyond the scope of this website, I've found suppliers use the phrase "turnkey PCB manufacturing" or "turnkey assembly" to describe this service.

In my experience with one provider, we provide GERBER files, drill files, and footprint position files for board manufacturing, along with a bill of materials listing every component. Usually the manufacturer takes care of component sourcing, though occasionally we've needed to ship them hard-to-find parts on consignment. A few weeks later, assembled boards arrive in the mail, ready to install in our system.

Our orders are typically in the 50-100 board range; smaller orders are possible, but since a lot of the cost is in the setup, the per-board cost is significantly higher for small runs.

Most manufacturers keep a decent supply of commonly-used parts. For very small scale test boards, I tend to design around whatever parts the manufacturer has in their supply. I use a different manufacturer (well-known, based out of China), get them to populate whatever passives and common ICs they have in stock, leaving me with just a few larger and/or through-hole components to assemble myself. It's usually in the $30 per order range, but you can get it under $10 if you don't pay for rush shipping.

Answer (score 3):

Yes some do, but those that I know of offer a relatively narrow range of components, so if you use a particular micro, switch-mode ic or whatever that they don’t stock then you’re out of luck.  I suppose if you choose a manufacturer and then design around what they have then it could work.  It can be worthwhile to talk to a contract manufacturer even for relays all quantities, probably not for 10 off but 50 or 100 units might be cost effective.  I don’t think it’s appropriate to name suppliers here, otherwise I would.

Comment: If the manufacturer doesn't have all of the components, you can send them the ones they don't have (assuming you trust the manufacturer, which should be a condition anyway). I once sent a manufacturer parts worth far more than the assembly cost, and it turned out fine.

Comment: Some assembly places will quote the assembly job if you send them the BOM. Whether they have the parts or not.

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience with JLCPCB, it works just fine. Also for 5 boards.

You submit:

- the gerber plus nc drill files
- A BOM csv file
- A pick place file, also csv

If you care about fast and efficient it’s recommended to use their standard stock. In Altium I made those components available in my library with a J (jlc) in their name. As a parameter I also included the C number, their catalog number, it’s added in the BOM file.

When you create the footprints add the 3D step, assembly outline, assembly center mark, courtyard, .designator text, etc (Look at the footprint movie from Robert Feranec with Hausherr [Extensive footprint movie](https://youtu.be/cMxXea16Hxc)) to make the process smoothly. The courtyard also prevents components being too close.

On the JLCPCB site I just enter all details, like double sided assembly and upload the files. Select and confirm the components and check their angle. It’s advisable to use recognizable overlay markings for pin 1 and anode/kathode. Always let JLCPCB confirm your production files with you.

If they don’t have the necessary components available, you can order the needed ones by global source (like mouser) and let it being send to them. (For your personal stock at JLCPCB) Extra waiting time: 1-2 weeks… Be careful to order extra for assembly mistakes, some also need a minimum to order. Made this mistake, took another 2 weeks. It’s a pity you can’t finish the ordering process and wait for the components, you just have to do this again when the components arrived.

Be aware: I pay with a creditcard, when the order has to be cancelled because of footprint issues etc, they pay back the prepaid money… But my CC company (visa) keeps the administrative charge. Around 60€. It’s learn-money and I write down the reason of rejection in a paper I always check for next time orders. PCBWAY does the auditing first and charges you when they accept. But are also more expensive.

JLCPCB at this moment doesn’t solder trough hole components, but they are easily done yourself. They supply them separately. But I wouldn’t be surprised if they change this very soon; they already changed a lot of options like tenting and capping, more layer boards etc.

Comment: NB: https://jlcpcb.com/parts and for ordering your own parts they don’t have in stock, or too less: https://smt.jlcpcb.com/smtPrivateLibrary?index=1 (login needed)

Comment: Re: "But my CC company (visa) keeps the administrative charge". In all my life I have never been charged an "administrative charge" by a bank or a card network like visa. Must be a weird european thing

Answer (score 0):

Usually PCB fabrication and PCB assembly are two different businesses.

But there are some companies that offer low volume assembly for prototypes. I'm sure there are a couple more, but the companies I know of of the top of my head are JLCPCB, CircuitHub and Eurocircuits.

The main thing here is that you have to figure out how to provide data to them. They usually require a specific way to keep setup cost low and being able to offer low volume assembly for a reasonable price. Or they might restrict you to a subset of components that they already have in their library (e.g. for their internal DFM checks) or have restrictions on specific mounting types (through holes, BGAs, ...).